# Is there a way to stop Jenkins build step if fails more than x times

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a build setup which uses chained freestyle Jenkins projects. And that setup contains some build projects that fails frequently due to DB issues.

If the specific build project is failed, it will automatically restart that build project.

However I don't want to run build to run on a loop if it fails continuously.  How can I set a condition to stop the build  if it was failed more than x times ?

Answer (score 1):

[Naginator](https://plugins.jenkins.io/naginator/) plugin provides `Maximum number of successive failed builds` option to choose how many times to retry running the job.[image]